# Is it a bug for the function ifelse?

Tags: r, if-statement

Here is my vector:

```
x <- c("a", "b", "c")
```

I am going to extract only the odd elements from the vector so I write something like this:

```
ifelse(length(x) > 0, x[seq(from = 1, to = length(x), by = 2)], NA)
```

But the result returned is just only`"a"`. However, if I check the condition and run the TRUE statement separately, I got different results.

```
length(x) > 0   #TRUE
x[seq(from = 1, to = length(x), by = 2)]   # "a" "c"
```

Does anyone know why? Thank you!

Comment: `ifelse` requires all arguments to have equal length.  Here, the first argument is of length 1 and second (based on the example) is 2.  So, if the first argument gives FALSE, it will be recycled, similarly if it is TRUE, it gets recycled.  In this case an `if/else` loop is needed

Comment: Oh I got what you mean. An if/else statement is a better option for this case. Thank you! @akrun

Comment: Generally one use `ifelse` as a vectorized option for `if/else` i.e. the length of the logical vector is greater than 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to `?ifelse`

> A vector of the same length and attributes (including dimensions and "class") as test and data values from the values of yes or no

where 'test', 'yes', 'no' are arguments

```
ifelse(test, yes, no)
```

In the concerned example, there is mismatch in length between 'test', 'yes', 'no'.  The first one returns a logical vector of length 1, second of 2 and third of 1 again.  This creates an imbalance.  In this example, it is a TRUE, so it is returning the first element of 'yes'.  Instead, we can use `if/else`

```
if(length(x) > 0) x[seq(from = 1, to = length(x), by = 2)] else NA
#[1] "a" "c"
```